# How can I convert from Oracle SQL to DB2?

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

masters~
I'm having trouble converting Oracle SQL to DB2.

I need to change these Oracle SQLs to DB2.

Please help me

```
CREATE TABLE ABC (
   AA VARCHAR(10 BYTE) WITH DEFAULT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
);


CREATE TABLE CBA (
BB  INTEGER(22) NOT NULL
) PCTFREE 10 TABLESPACE CC STORAGE (INITIAL 32K NEXT 32K) NOLOGGING;
```

Comment: Have you tried to ommit the words in bold?

Comment: The question is not "how", but "why"!

Comment: @Boheman the "why" is irrelevant. They could be adding support for DB2 or they could be merging with a company where the application has to now run on DB2, who cares?

Comment: Have you tried reading the DB2 manual?

Comment: Which version of DB2?  And why do you appear to be storing a timestamp value as a character column?

Comment: EmmanuelN: I believe bold character doesn't matter. a_horse_with_no_name: I am perusing the maunal carefully but can't find the answer yet. @X-Zero I'm using DB2 Express-C 9.7 version

Comment: The above DDL isn't valid in Oracle (11g - earlier versions might give different results) and thus I can't see how to convert it to its DB2 equivalent. In particular: 1. In the definition of table ABC, "WITH DEFAULT" is not valid. 2. Column ABC.AA is too small to hold its default value. 3. INTEGER(22) is not valid in Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What with all the concerns @Bob Jarvis mentioned in the comment to the original post, here is some rough equivalents that might get you by.  You should probably consult the [Information Center documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp) a bit for further reference.

```
CREATE TABLE ABC (
   AA TIMESTAMP WITH DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP GENERATED BY DEFAULT
);


CREATE TABLE CBA (
    BB  BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

If you're generating timestamps, you should store them as such, not as character strings.

Also, there is a `NOT LOGGED` option on DB2 tables, but it is only valid for `LOB` data types.  (Or, there is `NOT LOGGED INITIALLY`, which will not log any changes that are applied in the same unit of work as the table creation, which is useful, for example, when importing data from another source [file or other table, perhaps])